# Langchain : Querying from postgresql database using SQLDatabaseChain

Tags: python, django, postgresql, langchain

i am querying postgresql database using langchain. For this i am using Claude llm whose api key is anthropic_api_key. I am connecting postgresql database using SQLDatabase.from_uri() method.

this is my code inside file postgres_db.py

```
from langchain import  SQLDatabase
from constants import anthropic_key
from langchain.chat_models import ChatAnthropic
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
import os

os.environ["ANTHROPIC_API_KEY"] = anthropic_key

API_KEY = anthropic_key

# Setup database
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    f"postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:umang123@localhost:5432/delhi_cime_2",
)

# setup llm
llm = ChatAnthropic(temperature=0)

# Create db chain
QUERY = """
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct postgresql query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer.
Use the following format:

"Question": "Question here"
"SQLQuery": "SQL Query to run"
"SQLResult": "Result of the SQLQuery"
"Answer": "Final answer here"

"{question}"
"""

# Setup the database chain
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True)


def get_prompt():
    print("Type 'exit' to quit")

    while True:
        prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")

        if prompt.lower() == 'exit':
            print('Exiting...')
            break
        else:
            try:
                question = QUERY.format(question=prompt)
                result = db_chain.run(question)
                print(result)
            except Exception as e:
                print("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",e)
                pass

get_prompt()
```

when i am executing the above script using python postgres_db.py command stuck in this error which i am attaching as a screenshot of terminal.
SQL query is correct in this screenshot as when i am executing this query i am getting the correct records i.e. 6 records from the database but it showing only 1 also giving a syntax error.
Please help me in solving this.

[error on terminal image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fpLR.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting is because of parsing issue. Output parser is an issue when you work with different chain and LLM.

You can try with DatabaseToolkit

```
    toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=self.llm)

    agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
        llm=self.llm,
        toolkit=toolkit,
        verbose=True
    )

    with get_openai_callback() as cb:
        res = agent_executor.run(query)
        print("SQL Query Result:")
        print(res)
```